# How do I access the magento log file using ONLY the web interface

Tags: log, web

We are getting orders from Magento that feeds into our Enfocus Switch computer.
I have an order that has given the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
  <message>Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-65d79324a87f6</message>
 </response>
```

I do not have access to the underlying OS, only the Magento web interface.
I have been through the menus but don't see how to access the log file.

Is it possible to view this logfile using only the web interface?

Comment: Hi @Shawn, Which magento version you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following extension to view the logs in the backend:

https://commercemarketplace.adobe.com/magecomp-magento-2-log-download.html

**Note:** The community version is free for the above extension. You only need to choose the open-source option in the Edition dropdown on the URL above.